# Django Session doesn't work enough

Tags: django, session, localhost

When I open session in django 1.4, everything is fine. I can read my session if I redirect my page with some form processes

*Example :*

```
<form id="processForm" action="http://localhost:8000" method="post">{% csrf_token %} 
   <input type="submit" value="Search"></input>
</form>
```

I'm working at localhost:8000 and memcached. The problem is when after I open a session, if I search localhost:8000 on browser, I can't read session like it's like never exits.

Codes:

**views.py**

```
def search(request):     
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    if request.session.get('name'):
        c.update({ 'hellomsg' : 'Hello:' + request.session["name"] })
    else:
        c.update({ 'hellomsg' : 'Hello: Guest' })        
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['q']:
            if not request.POST['q'] == "false":                
                c.update({ 'output' : request.POST['q'] })
    return render_to_response("form.html", c, context_instance= RequestContext(request))

def open_session(request):
    c = {}    
    c.update(csrf(request))
    if not request.session.get('name'):
        if request.POST['nametxt']:
            request.session['name'] = request.POST['nametxt']
            c.update({ 'hellomsg' : 'Hello:' + request.POST['nametxt'] })
        else:
            c.update({ 'hellomsg' : 'Error...'})
    else:
        c.update({ 'hellomsg' : 'You're already logged in...'})
    return render_to_response("form.html", c, context_instance= RequestContext(request))

def close_session(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    if request.session.get('name'):
        try:
            del request.session['name']
            c.update({ 'hellomsg' : 'logged out...'})
        except KeyError:
            pass
    else:
        c.update({ 'hellomsg' : 'Error'})        
    return render_to_response("form.html", c, context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^$', search),
    ('^session/$', open_session),
    ('^csession/$', close_session),
)
```

Comment: You should really format your code, coz its a mess up there!

Answer (score 2):

Sessions are automatically created in Django. See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/sessions/) pages.

To read or write to the session you can do `request.session['someting']`